# I have two TableViews on a single View Controller, how can I pass data to a separate View Controller based upon which TableView was tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, tableview

Firstly, I apologize if this question has been asked before or if it is relatively straightforward to answer. I am relatively new to Swift/programming in general and am still teaching myself as much as I possibly can. I normally check developer documentation/reddit/google for answers to questions I have. If there is a better way of finding answers or support, I would greatly appreciate any general tips or tricks if possible!

In the project I am currently working on, one of my view controllers contains two separate TableViews, each populated by filtered results from a master array. The master array is made up of lessons, each lesson having a name, learning type, and theme. The two filtered arrays are filtered based upon the learning type of the lesson:

```
var visualArray: [Module] = AllModules.modulesArray.filter { $0.learningType == .visual }
var kinestheticArray: [Module] = AllModules.modulesArray.filter { $0.learningType == .kinesthetic }
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to pass the name of the module and description of the module to a separate view controller based upon which lesson the user tapped. I have tried to accomplish this in the '**didSelectRowAt**' method and the '**prepare(for segue:)**' method to no avail. What I would like to happen is the text property of a label on the destination controller to show the name of the selected lesson, what actually happens is the label just stays the same.

Here is my current code for the prepare(for segue:) method mentioned above:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let tableView = UITableView()

    // Set up indexPath
    guard let visualIndexPath = visualTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow,
        let kinestheticIndexPath = kinestheticTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }
    let visualModules = visualArray[visualIndexPath.row]
    let kinestheticModules = kinestheticArray[kinestheticIndexPath.row]

    // Set up destination
    guard let destVC = segue.destination as? ModuleVC else { return }
    if tableView == visualTableView {
        print(visualModules.name, visualModules.description)
        destVC.moduleName = visualModules.name
        destVC.moduleDescription = visualModules.description
    } else if tableView == kinestheticTableView {
        destVC.moduleName = kinestheticModules.name
        destVC.moduleDescription = kinestheticModules.description
    }

}
```

Here is my current code for the destination view controller:

```
class ModuleVC: UIViewController {

var moduleName: String?
var moduleDescription: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setUI()

    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}

@IBOutlet var moduleNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var moduleDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

func setUI() {

    guard let moduleName = moduleName, let moduleDescription = moduleDescription else {return}
    moduleNameLabel.text = moduleName
    moduleDescriptionLabel.text = moduleDescription

}
```

}

Any help, even a small step in the right direction, would be immensely appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the problem is that you're instantiating a generic tableView in your `prepare(for segue:)` method, and then doing some sort of check to see if the tableView is equal to your visualTableView or kinestheticTableView. Neither of those conditions will ever be met because you're comparing them to the newly created tableView that has nothing in it, and isn't even laid out in your view.

It sounds like what you're trying to do should be accomplished in the `didSelectRow` delegate method for the UITableViewDelegate as you hinted at earlier. Sounds like you possibly didn't set it up right.

In the `didSelectRowAt` method of the UITableViewDelegate, when a tableView row is tapped, the delegate method will fire and it will pass along the tableView which was tapped as a parameter. You can then use that to run a check and it should succeed if one of those two tableViews are tapped. Here is an example of what I think you could do:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == visualTableView {
        let visualModules = visualArray[indexPath.row]
        print(visualModules.name, visualModules.description)
        // Now call your segue and pass along the data from those modules
    } else if tableView == kinestheticTableView {
        let kinestheticModules = kinestheticArray[indexPath.row]
        // Now call your segue and pass along the data from those modules
    }
}
```

Comment: when you say call the segue, do you mean call the prepare(for segue:) method, or setup the segue within the didSelectRowAt method?

Comment: @C0rvinus - I mean call the `perform(segue)` method to invoke your segue. Another thing you can do is to just create an instance of the new VC you want to present and call `present(viewController:)`. Then you won't even need to use a segue or setup anything in the `prepare(for segue:)` method. You can just assign the new VC's properties by doing something like `let newVC = NewViewControllerClassName()` and then say something like `newVC.arrayName = visualModels`, and then `present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: @C0rvinus - whenever you perform a segue, the `prepare(for segue)` method will be called before the segue is actually invoked, thus any preparatory work you do will be done so everything is ready once the segue is completed.

Comment: Ah! thank you for the clarification. Originally, I only had one segue from source view controller to target view controller, but now I have two. They are now from each tableView prototype cell to the destination view controller, I'm not sure if that changes anything. I tried the deselectRowAt method, but it still weirdly is not working. Since I have two segues now, I tried again at the prepare(for segue) method, but still no dice.